# Blender 3D Rigging Bone Troubleshooting

Tags: animation, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, bones

I know how to Rigging a Blender 3D, but after testing it, it worked well, but the right arm doesn't look like a problem in the armature, but it gets crumpled in a strange direction. And I thought it was the mirror, but it wasn't. I kept looking for a solution, but I couldn't find it. Please help me as soon as possible. Thank you very much. I'll leave a screenshot.
And Please Give .blend file
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ow I didn't know thanks^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select the arms and Clear the Parent.

Now select the arm again and Set Parent To Bone.

I think the vertex groups are not painted well.

I repainted the meshes but the result was not so good.

The best thing I could do is to reparent the objects.

See the image below:

[image]

**More:**

It's a good practice, as soon as you unparented the objects, to delete all the vertex groups of that object.

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much Much Much!!! You Saved me!!!! Thank you Soooooo Much <3

Comment: Could you give me the .blend file? Thank you very much for the solution, but I'm an introvert to Blender, so could you give me the .blend file? Sorry,